# Does an ID POCO property have to be case sensitive for RavenDB?

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, ravendb

I am using the Music Store sample data and I have a POCO like so:

```
public class Album
{
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; } /***** NULL *****/
    public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int CountSold { get; set; }

}
```

However when I retrieve the data the ID property is null. If I change the property to Id then it is populated. This seems to suggest that the property has to be a certain case.

Here is the data:

```
{
  "AlbumArtUrl": "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif",
  "Genre": {
    "Id": "genres/1",
    "Name": "Rock"
  },
  "Price": 8.99,
  "Title": "Let There Be Rock",
  "CountSold": 0,
  "Artist": {
    "Id": "artists/1",
    "Name": "AC/DC"
  }
}
```

Interestingly for the Genre & Artist POCO changing the case of the POCO property doesn't make a difference.  I wonder if its because its explicitly stated as a property in the JSON whereas the Id in the Album is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, we look for a property named "Id", and yes, **casing matters** in the property name.

You can change that convention by changing the `Conventions.FindIdentityProperty`

eg

Comment: Out of interest why doesn't it matter if the Genre/Artist POCO is ID or Id because either wau it gets populated